# InputFormatters is empty in Blazor Server side Side app (Razor Components) when using [FromBody] attribute in controller

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on a web game using Server side blazor (Razor Components) in Asp.Net Core 3.0 preview. I have a controller class that I am using to save the game data to the server, but whenever I make a post request with a valid JSON body, the controller failed to format the request body because it cannot find any IInputFormatter from the context.

I've been able to do simple GET requests, and POSTs without using a [FromBody] attribute, so I know my controller routing is working. But anytime I try using HttpClient SendJsonAsync or PostJsonAsync methods and try to read the JSON with the [FromBody] attribute, I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions.InputFormatters' must not be empty. 
At least one 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter' is required to bind from the body.

I also directly installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json to my projects just inn case, but no luck.

I register and add mvc to my services in my Server.Startup class

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorComponents<App.Startup>();
        services.AddMvc();

        //Register httpclient service
        if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
        {
            // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
            {
                // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
                var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<IUriHelper>();
                return new HttpClient
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.GetBaseUri())
                };
            });
        }
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}"); });
        app.UseRazorComponents<App.Startup>();
    }
```

My controller class and method:

```
public class GameController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Game/SaveGame")]
    public string SaveGame([FromBody]GameInfoBody gameInfo)
    {
         //save the game to database
    }
}
```

My client call in my Game.cshtml page:

```
public async Task<string> SaveGameToDatabase(GameEngine game)
{
    var request = new GameInfoPostModel()
    {
        gameInfo = new GameInfoBody
        {
            ID = game.ID,
            GameEngine = game,
            Players = game.Teams.SelectMany(x => x.Players).Select(x => new PlayerGameMapping() { PlayerID = x.ID }).ToList()
        }
    };

    try
    {
        var result = await Client.SendJsonAsync<string>(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Game/SaveGame", request);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Failed to save" + e.Message;
    }
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions.InputFormatters' must not be empty. At least one 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.IInputFormatter' is required to bind from the body.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinderProvider.GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory.CreateBinderCoreUncached(DefaultModelBinderProviderContext providerContext, Object token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(ModelBinderFactoryContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.GetParameterBindingInfo(IModelBinderFactory modelBinderFactory, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider, ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, MvcOptions mvcOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.CreateBinderDelegate(ParameterBinder parameterBinder, IModelBinderFactory modelBinderFactory, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider, ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, MvcOptions mvcOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.MvcEndpointDataSource.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<CreateEndpoint>b__0(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Reading documentation tells me that JsonFormatters are included by default. I've verified using Fiddler that my calls have the correct content type and valid JSON. I'm thinking I must not have configured the services correctly if it can't find any InputFormatters from the context, but I haven't found anyone else with this problem and I don't know what to try next. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: you're code seems to be fine... The problem is probably with the model binding. I'll try to solve this issue, if I can...

Comment: I also opened up an issue on github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7438

And have a small test project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/EricPalmer22/TestBlazorController (call is in the Counter page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
(follow this order...)

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

services.AddRazorComponents<App.Startup>();
```

Comment: Getting error: 'IMvcBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddNewtonsoftJson'

Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0

Comment: Aha! It's in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson package. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me `services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters();`